# wamp subdomain alias strange behaviour

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, localhost, wamp, alias

I am using WAMP on windows 7

Have made alias of zf2-tutorial.localhost, have added it in drivers/etc/hosts
Have also enabled the virtual host setting in:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Have set my alias in this file according to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I open zf2-tutorial.localhost it shows the zend page as expected. But when I am trying to open localhost page it shows this:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Disabling Virtual Host in httpd.conf, allows to open localhost but fail to open zf2-tutorial.localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/539850/after-setup-virtual-host-my-wampserver-has-strange-behavior).

In order to be able to access localhost while enabling Virtual Hosts, the first entry in your httpd-vhosts.conf needs to be named localhost and link to your web root.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "path/to/your/www/folder"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /path/to/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

See an example in step three of [Setup Apache to serve multiple sites](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/creating-multiple-virtual-websites-in-wampserver/).